# Deserializing a generic object from POST body

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebAPI endpoint that to takes in a generic object.

```
[HttpPost]
[ApiRoute("endpoint/{type}")]
public IHttpActionResult MyPostEndpoint(TypeEnum type, [FromBody] object myObject){}
```

We work on the object generically but then eventually convert it to our object type, but when we do we have to turn it into a JObject first, so grabbing the object looks like this:

```
var myfoo = ((JObject) object).ToObject<Foo>();
```

If I supply Foo directly as my POST parameter (e.g. `[FromBody] Foo myObject`) then it deserializes the incoming JSON to a Foo, but it won't deserialize to a generic C# object. Is there a way I can get it to deserialize to a generic C# object instead of leaving it a JObject so I can get myfoo like this instead?

```
var myfoo = (Foo) object;
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want the parameter specified as `Foo`?  Why does it need to be an `object`?  You said it works when specified as `Foo`.

Comment: You're using "generic" incorrect in this context. Anyway try changing `object` to `JObject`. You're better off creating the appropriate type and using that instead. APIs accepting any format where the API will figure out what was attempted to send break sooner than later.

Comment: In order for `(Foo) obj` cast to work, `obj` must already be assignable to `Foo` type. In this case, it would need to have already been deserialized into a `Foo` (or a descendant of `Foo`). By this point, it can't also be a `JObject` (unless `JObject` descends from `Foo`!) Is the motivation to gain control over the deserialization? Perhaps to catch an invalid cast?

Comment: Ah, I guess the motivation is in fact that the `type` parameter specifies what type of object is actually being passed? If you stick with this (essentially dependently-typed) pattern, I think you'll have to stick with `JObject`. But this is still probably better than `object`.

Answer (score 1):

As generic post method with data returned, I use. Than You can pass any class, so the request is more gerneric

```
 public class Requests
 {
 //...
 public async Task<ResultType> Create<ResultType>(string uri)
 {
 //TODO implementation of httpclient POST logic go here

var data = await results.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultType>(data);
return result;
}
```

Call method

```
List<foo> foos = new List<foo>();
Request requestToServer = new request();
Task.WaitAll(Task.Run(async =>(){
foos = await requestToServer.Create<Foo>("/foo");
}));
```

Now You can pass any predefined class

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do like following to have a loosely typed method

```
public static class HttpRequestHelper
    {
        public static async Task<T> GetDataModelFromRequestBodyAsync<T>(HttpRequestMessage req)
        {
            dynamic requestBody = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            object blobModelObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(requestBody);
            var blobModel = ((JObject)blobModelObject).ToObject<T>();

            return blobModel;
        }
    }
```

and usage is like following:

```
var blobModel = await HttpRequestHelper.GetDataModelFromRequestBodyAsync<RequestBlobModel>(req);
```

Hope This Helps

Answer (score 0):

.NET CLI

```
dotnet new web --name "GenericEndpointExample"
cd GenericEndpointExample
dotnet add package SingleApi
```

Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var app = builder.Build();

// map generic endpoint
app.MapSingleApi("sapi", 
    // add your generic request handler
    // for example, return the received data (already typed object)
    x => Task.FromResult(x.Data), 
    // add assemblies for resolving received data types
    typeof(MyClassName).Assembly, typeof(List<>).Assembly, typeof(int).Assembly);

app.Run();
```

Example request for type: MyClassName

```
POST /sapi/MyClassName
{"Name":"Example"}
```

Example request for generic: Dictionary<string,int?[]>

```
POST /sapi/Dictionary(String-Array(Nullable(Int32)))
{"key1":[555,null,777]}
```

[GitHub repository with examples](https://github.com/mustaddon/SingleApi)